# i uninstalled the python2 with sudo apt-get remove after that generates the following error , any help would be great,thankyou

Tags: apt, uninstall, python-2.7

```
root@odroid:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
root@odroid:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
64 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3clean on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
error running python rtupdate hook dh-python
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3clean on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
error running python rtupdate hook gdebi-core


dpkg: error processing package python3-html5lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-lxml:
 python3-lxml depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-lxml depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-lxml (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-numpy:
 python3-numpy depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-numpy depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-numpy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pil:armhf:
 python3-pil:armhf depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pil:armhf depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pil:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
 python3-pip depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-polib:
 python3-polib depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-polib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-apt
 python3-dbus
 language-selector-common
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-chardet
 python3-debian

 python3-lxml
 python3-numpy
 python3-pil:armhf
 python3-pip
 python3-polib
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You've not mentioned your OS/release details, and detail provided in heading should be repeated in the question (some browser/device configs do not show heading when viewing the opened page so your text has no question for those devices).  With your question, release details are **very** important as details differ with more modern releases.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Mate  (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.105-141 armv7l))

Comment: If this is something online, I'd take this opportunity to switch to a supported release of Ubuntu MATE.  All flavors of 16.04 LTS except for Kylin are now EOL, or for Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 the notice is https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425   Only main Ubuntu desktop, server, Ubuntu Core, (and for 16.04 Kylin) are still supported.  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to view for your actual device, but flavors only have 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) & 4.4 was the supported kernel of Ubuntu-MATE 16.04

Answer (score 0):

> i uninstalled the python2 with sudo apt-get remove

Well that is a mistake, at least with Ubuntu 16.04 (and earlier) including it's derivates.
Both Python versions are used within e.g. apt-get and all it's sub-functions.

And sadly, I have yet to spot a description of how to "repair" that mistake, other than reinstalling the OS.

If you have e.g. synaptic installed - you might try to reinstall Python2, but that might just be the beginning of what is required.

*NOTE: The above problem is probably present also with trying to upgrade the included python versions.*